# Twig and variables as numbers

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm getting a number from database (let's say, `10`) and I want to use it in `if/else` statement. Please note, that my variable may be equal to 0 or null.

My variable is `item.getRate.getRate`. I'm showing it in template like this:

> {{ item.getRate.getRate | default('0') }}

I try try to do a `if` statement by doing

> {% if item.getRate.getRate == 1 %}something{% endif %}

but it doesn't work.

It is runned in a loop, and one of the items has empty `getRate`. Could this be the problem? If yes - how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to check if variable exists ;)

> {% if item.getRate.getRate is defined %}{% if item.getRate.getRate ==
>   1 %} checked="checked"{% endif %}{% endif %}

A little long, but works. Anyone had a better idea? 'Cause it would be great, now it's kinda ugly :))

Comment: I don't know why you can getRate.getRate twice... But in anycase: In twig you can usually get away with not including the `get` prefix on attribute/function names. So you could shorten it like this: `{% if item.rate.rate is defined and item.rate.rate == 1 %}` -- Not much of a difference but it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine both tests to make your code easy to read.

```
{% if item.getRate.getRate is defined and item.getRate.getRate == 1 %} 
    checked="checked"
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming getRate having a non-zero, non-null value is necessary for this indication of boolean value, as your example suggests:

```
{% if not(not(item.getRate.getRate)) %} 
    checked="checked"
{% endif %}
```